# Stopping R from writing trailing whitespace into saved strings

Tags: string, r, svg

I'm creating a .svg file by paste strings together in R via paste(). Afterwards I write the string to a file via `writeChar()`. The problem is that R seems to add the whitespace characters `\r\n` at the end of the file. That makes the .svg file invalid. Google Chrome complains by saying

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 71 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I want to use the .svg files in Anki and Anki completely refuses to render them. Inkscape renders them fine.

Is there a way to prevent R from adding the `\r\n` at the end of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is your string, one way would be:

```
writeBin(charToRaw(x), 'out')
```

or better yet

```
writeChar(x, 'out', eos=NULL)
```

But you could also just use `cat`:

```
cat(x, file='out')
```